# python sqlalchemy CORE : results as dict

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to retrieve dicts from the result proxy object of a sqlalchemy ***CORE*** query.

This is the best I could do: (and I find it pretty lame)

```
s = select([table])
results = connection.execute(s)

for r in results:
    dict_ = dict(zip(r.keys(),r.values()))
```

I triedd using `.__dict__` and `._asdict()` attribute as mentionned in other question but they returned error `Could not locate column in row for column` . Is there a more idiomatic way of retrieving the resukt as a dict? I cannot fathom why the default behavior is to return tuples...

Comment: Doesn't `dict(r)` work? If it already has `.keys` and `.values`, can't you just use it as you would a dictionary anyway? Also, could you link the other question?

Comment: @johnsharpe yes - thx